# Are crossover and straight network cables interchangeable?

Tags: networking, lan, crossover-cable, cabling

Can a crossover cable be used as a *normal* cable too, when using with a router, switch,hub etc.

What situations may it not work in and are there other issues to be aware of when using crossover versus normal network cables?

Comment: The usual term is Ethernet **crossover** cable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wikipedia [says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_crossover_cable)

> Owing to the inclusion of Auto-MDIX capability, modern implementations of the Ethernet over twisted pair standards usually no longer require the use of crossover cables.

Which implies that a crossover Ethernet cable can be used in place of a straight-through Ethernet cable with recent equipment.

Older Ethernet hubs and switches sometimes had a special "uplink" port or a "normal/uplink" button for this purpose,

[image: Ethernet Hub with "normal/uplink" toggle-button]

I don't see these on recent equipment. I believe this is because they nowadays have Auto-MDIX and don't need special ports or buttons for crossover connections.

[image]

Comment: AFAIK the Auto-MDIX feature is mandatory for all Gigabit Ethernet ports, therefore if you have such a port at least on one side you have it for sure.

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that often you'll still see the equivalent of uplink ports where the switch has uplink ability at a different speed than its normal ports. 100M ports and 1G uplink, 1G ports and fibre uplink, etc.