# Ethernet cable with both ends different works in a router, why?

Tags: networking, router, ethernet

I found a ethernet cable at home that is different on both ends. They're like this:

**1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8** (bright-orange, orange, bright-green, blue, bright-blue, green, bright-brown, brown)
**3 6 1 4 5 2 7 8** (bright-green, green, bright-orange, blue, bright-blue, orange, bright-brown, brown)
I also tested the cable with a tester and the pins lighted up the same way.

I've always thought that an ethernet cable should have the same sequence on both ends (unless you're doing a connection between computers, then switching the receive/transmit makes sense), but since I'm connecting to a router, how can this work?

Obs: A normal ethernet cable (with equal sequences on both ends) works on the router too (as expected)

Comment: [This answer](https://superuser.com/a/1357425/432690).

Comment: thank you @KamilMaciorowski!