# Wiring 3 POE switches

Tags: wireless-networking

I have a POE switch in my house, garage, and barn for IP cameras. From house to garage is straight through wired. Cameras work fine. Do I need a crossover from garage to barn?

Comment: Your question is unclear, but if you're talking about Ethernet cabling, in practical terms nothing has needed a crossover cable since about 2004.

Comment: You should not need crossover cables unless the switches are very old (hubs instead of switches). See the answer here for more detail: https://superuser.com/a/1357425/673426

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to ethernet cables from switches, you do not need cross cables.

Cross cables are only if you go from pc to pc with just one cable and nothing in between that supports network functionality.

Modern switches are wired to allow for straight cables. They also understand traffic from and to other switches and alter the ports accordingly to work correctly.

Unless you have a really old switch or hub, this is the defecto standard for quite a while now.

Do note that you should not send a PoE signal from one PoE switch to another switch. If the PoE switch is smart enough, it will just not work, but if not, then you will burn out the other switch. PoE sends high voltages over certain lines and is only meant to reach the target device through a straight cable.

Also note that if you send a PoE signal over a crossover cable, you can damage the device as the high voltage power goes over the wrong internal cables. If the PoE switch is smart enough, it will fail the negotiation with the crossover cable and nothing happens, alter the port itself so it sends the signals correclt and thus work (don't try), but if not, then the device on the other end, despite it being a PoE device, could burn out.

So short answer: Only use straight cables but ensure that PoE devices get their power directly from a PoE capable sender, and that a PoE sender is not sending its power to anything but a PoE receiving device.

When connecting your switches, ensure that you link them through non-PoE ports.